# Batch file string formatting, wmic issue?

Tags: batch-file

Basically, I'm trying to write a batch file which loops through each of the local drives and searches for a file. My issues specifically pertains to concatenating the file path.

In my code I have a `filename` and a `driveletter`. My desired output is `driveletter\filename`.

I am able to echo the filename and filepath individually, but when I try to combine them to get `driveletter\filename`, the drive letter is empty. I've read that wmic results in a carriage return at the end of the text, but none of the suggested fixes seem to help.

Here is a stripped down version code showing the issue:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set filename=helloworld.txt


for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value') do (

SET driveletter=%%d

echo %%d
echo !driveletter!
echo !driveletter!\!filename!
DIR /s !driveletter!\!filename!)

pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "works always way" (process the output in another `for` to get rid of the carriage return):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value') do for %%i in (%%d) do echo -%%i-
```

the "works for this special case way" (getting a token without carriage return; here: between `=` and `:`, re-adding the `:`afterwards):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==:" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" get name /format:value') do echo -%%d:-
```

The problem with the second one is, you have to think about every single `wmic` output, how to get a token that is not the last one in the line, but it might be a bit better readable.